# Compare DataTables and conditionally update one

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, ado.net

I have two DataTables - one is created from a csv file, the other from a DB table.

[image]

1. How do I?
         Compare both DataTables based on id and name.
2. if record exists in: DataTableFromFile and not in DataTableFromDB - insert new record in DataTableFromDB
3. if record exists in: DataTableFromDB and not in DataTableFromFile  - update the end date in DataTableFromDB
4. if record exists in both: update DataTableFromDB from the values in DataTableFromFile
5. I can loop through the collection but that's too time consuming.
6. I do not want to do this operation in Database

Comment: _"I can loop through the collection but that's too time consuming"_ Well, have you tried it? If so, show your code and explain the issue. How you want to compare all rows without looping?

Comment: What code you have written for this? What issue you are facing with that_

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable and not a strongly typed object model?

Comment: The number of records make the looping time consuming - very large file more than 200k records on both sets.

Comment: Cannot use strong typed object... this is traditional ado.net code. at best I can use linq to objects

Comment: For 2 - insert new record where? For 3 - update end date to what?

Comment: Why compare on both id and name? Is it possible to have duplicate id's or for name to change or be different in two? Which wins to decide record exists?

Comment: How much will you pay for doing your work for you? SO Is NOT a code writing service, it's a Q&A website. Ask a specific question, get a specific answer. Don't come here asking people to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert both datatable into a dictionary using

```
datatable.AsEnumerable()
.ToDictionary<DataRow, string, string>(row => row[0].ToString(),
                                       row => row[1].ToString());
```

and you can perform any action after that.

Comment: Thanks Amit Tiwari... I even went a step further and converted the DataTable to a List<T>. Implemented the IEqualityComparer  interface and did a List.Except() etc - but the time taken by casting takes away the benefits of Linq to Object queries. Finally I implemented the functionality as a Store Proc in Sql server - using Merge. Thanks all for helping. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: No problemo mate